# All Occurences of a character in a column in Teradata

Tags: teradata, repeat

I have a column which contains multiple column values bound together.
Each of them is separated using "{" and "}". I need to seggregate these values and put each of them as separate columns so I can use them later.

e.g DataColumn: {Name = X}{Age = Y}{Gender = M}{Date = 180328}. It will only have these 4 values always.

Output I need is 4 different columns(with "Name" as header) and their values beneath the column header.

Comment: Always the same order *name/age/gender/date*?

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks a bit like JSON, then it would be really easy.

Try using NVP (*Name-Value-Pair*):

```
Nvp('}'||data_col||'{', 'Name', '}{', '\ =\ ')
```

- must add leading '}' and a trailing '{'
- the delimiter between *name* and *value* must include the spaces: ' = '
- the *name* is case-sensitive

If your data doesn't follow those rules you might have to switch to STRTOK or REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
RegExp_Substr_gpl(data_col, '({name ?= ?)(.+?)}',1,1,'i', 2)
```

`RegExp_Substr_gpl` is undocumented and adds a *capture group* parameter.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. I tried using the RegExp_Substr_gpl. This gives the result. But it picks up all characters starting from 'name' till the end of the datacol value. If I wanna restrict the data to only pick the value that comes in 'Name', is there a way?

Comment: @AswathM: Strange, works for me. What's your Teradata release? This also works (for me): `RegExp_Substr_gpl(data_col, '{name ?= ?(.+?)}',1,1,'i', 1)`

Comment: Thanks you so much. This suggestion works. Thanks a lot!!! I use TD 14.

Comment: If the number of data points in this column is unkown, is it possible to extract all of the available ones. The "Name/ Age/ gender/ Date" doesnt help here. I have more data points and I wanna take them all. Is it possible ?